# Rails 3.1 assets:precompile Connecting to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy an application to Heroku after upgrading to Rails 3.1 with the asset pipeline.  I ran into the common issue mentioned on Heroku's [troubleshooting page](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting) when receiving the error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused 
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting 
TCP/IP connections on port xxxx?
```

I took the suggestions on the page and added the following to my config/application.rb file (after also trying to add it to the individual [environment].rb files to no effect)

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I've modified my database.yml file to point my production environment to a non-existant database, but when running the assets:precompile task locally, I get the following:

```
> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
FATAL:  database "my_nonexistant_database" does not exist

Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm trying to figure out what part of my application is trying to initialize the database so that I can fix it, but I've run out of ideas for getting more debugging information than this.

**Anyone have any tips for either getting more information about where my app is trying to init the DB, or for fixing the underlying problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the new labs feature http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile which will make variables available at slug compile time.

Comment: Note though that this is still *very* beta and could be yanked at any time.  Tread with care.