# What is the proper way to avoid the rake assets:precompile error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm running on Rails 3.2.2 and deploying on a Cedar stack. I still get the following error:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Even the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) suggests setting `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` to false, but mentions:

> be sure to test rake assets:precompile locally before deploying. It
>   may expose bugs where your assets reference application objects or
>   methods, since those are still in scope in development mode regardless
>   of the value of this flag.

Some articles such as this [one](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/) suggest using [Heroku labs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile). But even this, comes with its own implication, since it is still on beta.

I've read on several other sources online, including:

[Rails 3.1 assets:precompile Connecting to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728257/rails-3-1-assetsprecompile-connecting-to-database)

[rake assets:precompile not working on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787766/rake-assetsprecompile-not-working-on-heroku)

All come with different solutions. So what is the proper way of avoiding this error? Anyone experience any big problems with Heroku labs? Is there a better approach?

**PS**. Just to be clear. Is running `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development` or `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` the proper way of running this locally?

Comment: Does the error-log tells you something useful?

Comment: It would indicate looking at 
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting I've read mixed results about applying the solution on the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that your application is trying to connect to postgres when you're running that rake task.  The only way to get rid of the error is to either stop this from happening, or to use the `user_env_compile` add-on that you mention.

Answer (score 1):

(1) I always add this as you suggested

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

(2) But also, if using ActiveAdmin and/or Devise, exclude their routes when precompiling  assets by coding routes.rb as follows

```
  unless ARGV.join.include?('assets:precompile')
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

    devise_for :admin_users, ...etc....
    devise_for :users, ...etc...

    devise_scope :user do
    get "/login", ..etc
  end
```

as per [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/474) and elsewhere